# How should I manage a parallel optimization of an instance method using ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, oop, shared-memory, concurrent.futures, nevergrad

### Useless intro

Hi everyone,

I'm having trouble with parallel use of nevergrad library. However, my question is about my implementation. It seems my OOP skills are not good. As the code is too long to reproduce here I will hypothesize while being specific.

### The problem setup

First, I have a class that inherits from `Algorithm`, let's say it is `Rotation`.
Second, I created an `Optimizer` class that helps me optimize any algorithm,

```py
class Optimizer:
  def __init__(self, algorithm):
    self.algorithm = algorithm
```

and one can define

```py
cfg = some_dict  # configuration dict
rot_algorithm = Rotation(cfg)  # an algorithm instance
rot_optimizer = Optimizer(rot_algorithm)  # an optimizer instance that works over an algorithm instance
```

Now, two more things:

1. Inside `Optimizer` there is a method `optimize_params` that uses `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` to optimize another method named `Optimizer.obj_fun` (see the end of the question).
2. The algorithms have, in general, internal variables that modify their behavior. For example, we could imagine that `rot_algorithm` has an internal variable named `angle` that will be modified during the optimization.

## The question

I found that `rot_algorithm.angle` was a variable that the threads had in common, that is, it could be modified by some thread while another had already set the value. That makes the results useless. How should I refactor my code in order to avoid this behavior?

#### Use of `ThreadPoolExecutor`

```py
        with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(
            max_workers=optimizer.num_workers
        ) as executor:
            r = optimizer.minimize(
                self.obj_fun,
                executor=executor,
                batch_mode=False,
            )
```

Comment: You need to figure out a way to present the section of code that you think is the cause of the problem.

Comment: You are aware of [thread local data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-local-data)?

Comment: @PaulCornelius I know, that was the best I could do today. If I manage to reproduce the problem I will update the question immediately.

Comment: @wwii I was not aware, seems useful, thank you. However, the multi-threading is not implemented by me but by nevergrad. I tried to pose the question as a conceptual one where the code inside the `with` is fixed.

Comment: The Rotation and Optimizer classes are not yours?

Comment: Yes, they are. But how would you do it? If I define `mydata = threading.local()` then I should do `mydata.local_obj = self.copy()` or something like that?

Comment: Can you change your code so you don't modify rot_algorithm.angle, perhaps by introducing a new variable that is local to the calculation?  That would seem to be an easy thing to try compared to these other solutions, which ALSO require you to create a new variable that is modifiable so that you can leave rot_algorithm.angle alone.  You can't fix this problem as described without changing the way you use rot_algorithm.angle.

Comment: Thank you all, I ended up using `threading.local` as @wwii suggested and I commented afterwards.